# Do you know why Django ls might not show up in project directory?

Tags: python, django, powershell

I tried to use django-admin.py from your virtualenv virtual environment but the manage.py and other files do not get created. I tried using the ls command and nothing shows up in the project directory. I am using version 3 of Django and I ran it using powershell in adminstrator mode.  Please help!
Thank you very much,
Josh

Answer (score -1):

use something like this first make sure where your current working directory is using 'pwd' command and after that use this command 'django-admin startproject nameofyourproject .'

Comment: Thank you very much Kishan!